# Windows 8, problems to show cameras in a flash application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, windows-8, firewire

I have a flash application that shows at screen the cameras that the operating system detects, and works fine on windows 7 but now, in windows 8, i have troubles with several cameras. For example firewire cámeras or screen capture driver.

I made a simple test application:

[Test](http://mainstream.atnova.com/test/testCamaras.html)

The same code executed like an air application seems to work, and the same webpage, running in windows 7, shows all the cameras right.

Is there any bug on flash player for windows 8?

Thanks.

Comment: are you testing it in desktop version of ie (not metro version)

Comment: yes, sorry, desktop version

Comment: btw - my camera worked with your test page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you test with various browsers?, I think the problem is the permissions to inspeck the hardware or drivers executions

Comment: I tested with Internet Explorer, Chrome and FireFox. On IE and Chrome the camera is not listed, on FF is listed but don't show the image.

camera.names.length returns different values depending on situation. Example:

At FlashDevelop, debug returns all my connected cameras. But when i open the resulting swf at the browser, or embed that swf into a windows form application, shows me only my webcam.

With Windows 7, Internet Explorer and Windows Form application works well. Now i just see that in ff and chrome not.